# Problema con Vegas js y base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo un problema con el plugin `Vegas.js`, al llamar mis imagenes de la base de datos, no las puedo ver, no me aparecen en el plugin, pero si hago un `console.log` y copio el texto en el plugin si aparecen, este es mi codigo:

```
$.get('ajax/slides.php', function(data) {
   $('#slideMain').vegas({
     slides: [ data ]
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
AJAX file
$slide = new slideManager();
$slide ->showSlideController();
```

`PHP`

```
public function showSlideController()
{
  $answer = slideModel::showSlideModel("slides");
  foreach($answer as $row => $item){
     echo '{ src: "'.$item['path'].'" },'; // Incluso asi no funciona
  }
}
```

Si alguien me pudiera decir que estoy haciendo mal, se los agradeceria mucho

Comment: [edt] y agrega la respuesta de la base de datos, es posible que tengas un caracter inválido. Usa try/catch o para obtener la descripción del error _(si tiene)_

Comment: Gracias por responder, mira, no me da ningun error, y la base de datos si me muestra las imagenes, el problema es que no puedo pasar esos datos al plugin, y en javascript tampoco me da error, simplemente no aparece nada.

Comment: podrías imprimir el fuente generado para ver como están las rutas? creo que el problema está allí. Por cierto data lo llenas con una función similar a `showSlideController()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aqui esta la solucion, por si alguien mas lo necesita

```
$.each(slide, function(i, slideData) {
        slides.push( {src: slideData['path']} );

    });
```